# Use the same AsyncTask to update different views

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a button on 6 different Activities. Clicking on that button does almost the same task with different params depending on the Activity.

This will be done using an `AsyncTask` and in `onPostExecute()` the button state will be changed.

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Task().execute("param1", "param2");
    }
}

private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //background task using params[0], params[1]
        return "success" or "error";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result == "success") {
            //change the someButton state
        }else{
            //show an error message
        }
}
```

Instead of having the same AsyncTask in all the 6 Activities, how can I use a single Asynctask from all the Activities and change the respective view?

Comment: Using the context of the activity. You can pass the context as a parameter to the Asynctask.

Comment: Yeah no problem is showing a toast etc.., But how can I change the view of that specific Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Task, with methods onSuccess, onFailure and override them.

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //background task using params[0], params[1]
        return "success" or "error";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result == "success") {
            onSuccess(result);
        }else{
            onFailure(result);
        }
    }

    protected void onSuccess(String result) {};
    protected void onFailure(String result) {};
}
```

and then in activity use it like this:

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Task(){
            @Override
            protected void onSuccess(String result){
                // do what you want
            }
            @Override
            protected void onFailure(String result){
                // do what you want
            }
        }.execute("param1", "param2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `Task` in its own file and make it public.

Create a callback interface:

```
public interface TaskCallback {
    public void onSuccess(String result);
    public void onFailure(String errorMessage);
}
```

Give such a callback to your `Task`:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TaskCallback callback; 

    public Task(TaskCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //background task using params[0], params[1]
        return "success" or "error";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        } else{
            callback.onFailure(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And then implement the callback when creating the `Task` instance in your activity:

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        private TaskCallback callback = new TaskCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                //change the someButton state
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String errorMessage) {
                //show an error message
            }
        }
        new Task(callback).execute("param1", "param2");
    }
}
```